# Integrate Artifactory into Jenkins Grails project

Tags: grails, jenkins, artifactory

I am currently trying to integrate Artifactory 4.8.1 with Jenkins 2.8 and having some trouble. I currently have the Artifactory Jenkins plug-in installed and configured to link to our Artifactory server. That connection is working and is all good. My issue though is I am not sure how to configure my settings in Jenkins to send artifacts from a build using Grails to Artifactory. I only see examples online for Maven, Ant and Gradle builds, but not Grails. I tried using a Generic Artifactory Integration, but it is not updating Artifactory.

Below are some screenshots of my Jenkins configuration:
[image]
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Which Grails version? If 3.x, it is based on Gradle and just use Gradle approach. It works for us perfectly. For Grails 2.x we have used maven before, there was no need for Artifactory plugin in Jenkins

Comment: When are build compiles it says it is using Grails 2.5.0 even though I have it set-up in Jenkins to use the latest version of Grails which I believe is 3.1.8. Which method do I go with then? If it is just the Maven way can you explain a bit more how that is done? How would it send the artifact to Artifactory without the Artifactory plugin?

Comment: For Grails 2.5.x you can use release plugin. See documentation here: https://grails.org/plugin/release

Comment: Ok so I downloaded the plugin and added it to my project and have it set-up to build plug-in. Now how would I use this plugin with Jenkins?

Comment: Our team found another way around this. We set up a second job in jenkins where we used the copy artifacts plugin to get the artifact out of original project. We then were able to publish the artifact to artifactory.